# linq to sql query with multiple where parameters

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I'm currently writing a search function in ASP.NET MVC 4 with the Entity Framework. However, I've hit a roadblock for which I can only find "bad" solutions.

My search functions gets back a model which consists of 4 parameters:

```
String Name
String Street
String Code
String Province

List<Query> query = (from t in Model select t).ToList();
```

Now I'd like to filter on my search input. However, a user can decide to fill in as many search fields as possible. He can decide to use Name and Street, or Name, Street and Province, or ...

The only real solution I was able to find consists of making my query and `IQueryable` and check whether or not a field has been filled with an `if`, then use a `.Where` to update the query.
As this would currently give m 5 queries, I'm wondering on whether or not there is a better solution that I'm missing here.

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If I understand you correct. You might want something like this:

```
string Name;
string Street;
string Code;
string Province;
var query=(from t in Model select t);
if(Name!=null)
{
    query=query.Where (q =>q.Name==Name);
}
if(Street!=null)
{
    query=query.Where (q =>q.Street==Street);
}
if(Code!=null)
{
    query=query.Where (q =>q.Code==Code);
}
if(Province!=null)
{
    query=query.Where (q =>q.Province==Province);
}
List<Query> ls = query.ToList();
```

You will have a `IQueryable` when you add the where statements and when you do the `ToList()` that sql will execute.

**Update**

To answer the comment of Luis Hernández. So this is how it works. When you select from the model in this case the collection type is `IQueryable`. This means that it has not been executed against the database. For the query to execute you need to apply some of the final metod. To tell linq that it will actually do the database call. These are for example

```
ToList()
FirstOrDefault()
SingleOrDefault()
Single()
First()
ToDictionary()
```

So when we append the Where clauses without using `ToList()`. There is no execution of the query.

Please try the query in [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/)

Comment: Yes, that's the solution I found online. I was wondering on whether or not there is a cleaner way to code this.

Comment: If you want to stay `IQueryable`. Then this is what i think the way to do it

Comment: May be there is more code, but this the most optimized (and probably the best) one. Check the resulting SQL query in [linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/)

Comment: Why?? You are check if something is null (Not complicated). If the value is something then add a where statement (Not complicated).

Comment: I have a doubt about this solution. What if there is a big bunch of data being recovered from the DB? As far as can see (pardon me if im wrong) this will recover the whole colection of data from database, then filter the results given the specified criteria, am i right?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the concise explanation, Arion. I appreciate it.

Comment: @LuisHernández : No problem. Your feedback made the answer better

Answer (score 2):

Use the Entity filter class you find here : https://servicelayerhelpers.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/32810#537055

so first specify your filter and after that just apply it to your query.

    Example:

```
var filter = EntityFilter
.Where(c => c.Name == came)
.Where(c => c.City == city);

var customers = FindCustomers(filter);

Customer[] FindCustomers(IEntityFilter filter)
{
var query = context.Customers;
query = filter.Filter(query);
return query.ToArray();
}
```

more info on: https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=66

Answer (score 0):

You casn try some thing like this

```
from cars in tblCars
where (cars.colorID == 1) && (cars.Wieght > 500) && (cars.Active == true)
select cars;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Arion's solution is of course very good**, I tried to make it a little less repetitive using reflection, hope it helps.

```
        Type myType = myObject.GetType();
        IList<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>(myType.GetProperties());

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
        {
            object propValue = prop.GetValue(myObject, null);
            if (propValue != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(q => prop.GetValue(q, null) == propValue);
            }
        }
```

**EDIT:**

I've edited it to work on all properties. of course you still need some things around for this to work, but once you understand how to work with it, you can use it as a utility for all of your code, instead of hardcoding it for every type

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this only works for the Name value which you specified. As I have 3 other values as well, I don't see how this could work.